# When designing a second-order RLC band pass filter, how can we choose whether to use the series form or parallel form?

Tags: analog, filter, passive-filter

Second order RLC filter can be realized in series and parallel forms.

Suppose we need a high Q factor, if we choose a series form, we need the inductor to have a larger value than the capacitor and the resistor.

Conversely, if we choose a parallel form, we need the inductor to have a much lower value than the capacitor and resistor.

So in real application, how can we decide which form to use?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the pass band frequency?

Comment: If you are driving from a resistive source into a resistive load, those impedances would dominate the Q of a series circuit : it may be impossible to achieve high Q. A parallel circuit is often driven from a tap on the inductor, allowing the resonant cct itself to be high Q : look at IF filters on AM radios from the valve days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One wishes to choose a resonating inductance that is as small as possible, since the iron or ferrite required to achieve high-inductance often has undesirable characteristics. A large inductance may also require many windings of copper wire.
A resonator sometimes is mechanical, such as a piezoelectric crystal, or ceramic resonator. In these cases, inductance is often quite high, but cannot be easily chosen by the designer.

Both source resistance and load resistance must be considered, one or both are usually out of control of the designer. When both are low, the series RLC resonator yields a high-Q resonator with least inductance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjs6H1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When both source and load resistance are high, parallel RLC resonator yields a high-Q resonator with least inductance (below). Both these series and parallel example circuits  have similar "loaded" Q.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYpDTH.png)</sup>

Where you have a crystal resonator, the equivalent inductive reactance is often very, very high. For reasonable source and load resistances found in electronic circuits, the series form is more reasonable than the parallel form:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU3AC2.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Its about the impedance at the resonant frequency. If I've understood your terminology correctly, the series version provides a short-to-ground (or whatever), and thus a low impedance on the driving source. The parallel version provides a high-impedance at resonance, and low impedance at low and high frequencies.

Comment: thank you for your reply. So if the filter is put at the output and it is necessary to deliver a constant output current, then the impedane of the filter has to be high. So a parallel form should be used. On the other hand, if it is required to deliver a contant voltage to the next stage, then the output RLC filter should have a low impedance. In this case, a series form should be used. Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: A constant-current situation does not really apply to an AC voltage, and the filter is only effective for AC voltages. For your situation, I would pick the filter with the DC path through the input-output path. In other words, pay attention to how current passes through the inductor, and how it does not pass through the capacitor and/or crystals.